# Parseval's theorem and $L_2$ space

Tags: fourier-analysis, parsevals-identity

I need to show $\sum|\hat{f}(n)|< \infty$ if $f$ is continuously differentiable on the circle $\mathbb{T}$.

Using the fact that $\hat{f}(n)= \frac{\hat{f}'(n)}{in}$, Cauchy-Schartz and Parseval's identifty, I get
$$\left|\sum \hat{f}(n)\right| < \frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{T}}|f'(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t}$$

But this  last integral is the norm of $f'$ in the $L_2$ space. How do we know $f'$ is in fact in that space? Is it because $f$ is continuously differentiable?

Comment: @XanderHenderson question edited!

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then $f'$ is continuous.  Continuity on the torus implies boundedness.  Boundedness on a compact set implies finite $p$-norm for any $p$.  Thus your integral on the right converges.